# Using graphics.h in Codeblocks gives cannot find lbgi error

Tags: c++, codeblocks, bgi, winbgi

Im trying to install the graphics.h into codeblocks. However, when I run any code assosiated with graphics.h I get the message "ld.exe||cannot find -lbgi|". [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747110/c-graphics-h-lbgi-not-found) previous Stackoverflow question appears to be by someone with the same issue, I have tried downloading the file linked in the answer to the lib folder but the same error still appears. [image: Screenshot showing lib folder of compiler.]
Screenshot of compiler linker options:
[image: Screenshot of compiler options]

Comment: ProTip: don't use `graphics.h`.  If you need graphics in the console pick up a modern cross platform library like ncurses.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313534/how-to-use-graphics-h-in-codeblocks/46300800